# Getting unable to discover open pages. Can't run my test suite from jenkins in chrome browser

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this stack trace.

```
Default Logging level is set to ERROR
Loping for  strBrowserType chrome
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 42027
Tests run: 32, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 31, Time elapsed: 67.337 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setupSuite(com.ambab.carworkz.testcases.ServiceEstimatorTestTc)  Time elapsed: 66.668 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.06 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'ROBER-QA', ip: '192.168.0.70', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Results:

```
Failed tests: 
  ServiceEstimatorTestTc>Base.setupSuite:114 » WebDriver unknown error: unable t...

Tests run: 32, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 31

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

I'm running test suite from jenkins in chrome browser that is the time when I'm facing this issue. If I directly run the suite from eclipse IDE then it runs fine. When I run the same test suite in firefox then also it runs fine.

I've installed the latest version of chrome, and chrome driver. Running jenkins job with maven.

Tried using no-sandbox as well as changes in chrome browser setting of automatic detect setting. Jenkins also I'm running the job on master and there is no slave. Tried every possible solution regarding this problem. If any more solution there then please let me know.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the latest version of ChromeDriver should be 2.22, as per: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: @Josh I've used 2.22 as well.. Nothing seems to work. I'm stuck at this for past 2 days! Need to get this resolved asap! It's sucking way too much time..

Comment: Just to exclude this remote possibility as well, Jenkins is running on a windows machine as well, right?

Comment: @Morfic Yes It's running on a windows machine..

Comment: Ok, so it looks like 32 tests were successful while 1 failed, so we need to figure out why that is special. Perhaps you're overriding a method, closing the driver, etc? Any chance you could share the sources for a passing test, failing test and base class? Of course replacing or removing any sensitive information... Also I assume that jenkins is running via maven, and you're doing the same from the IDE?!

Comment: @Morfic There are 32 Test and I have skipped 31 out of them.. I'm running just 1 out of the 32. Secondly When I run the same script via eclipse IDE it runs perfectly without any error. It's only when I run it via Jenkins that is the time when I face this error.. as well as it runs fine for firefox so the problem is only with chrome.

Comment: You're right, sorry, i missed the `Skipped: 31` part. Next hunch, is the chrome version on the jenkins machine the same as on your own pc?

Comment: @Morfic I'm running the jenkins job on the same machine.

Comment: Then perhaps it's an ownership issue... Can you try to see if there's anything of value [logged by the chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging)?

Answer (score 0):

I've added this stuff and it solved it in my case. There also may be problem with user that is running jenkins (it should be set to Admin)

`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", DownloadsPath);
                options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Severe);
                options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
                options.AddArguments("test-type");
                options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
                options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
                var ChromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                ChromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                instance = new ChromeDriver(ChromeService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200));`